# e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Error reading PHY register

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Thinkpad T460 and /var/log/syslog is being spammed by this message

```
05.10.16 23:46  vitas-ThinkPad-T460 kernel  [87678.697881] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Error reading PHY register
```

It happens when I am connected using wifi. I suspect incompatible drivers or something. Wifi works OK, BUT at my work office it does not - connects and works for around 30seconds and then pings stop. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to file a bug report for this." I suspect incompatible drivers" more than likely... so we can't really help with that. Similar: https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/36/

Comment: I can't find the right cathegory for this there on sourceforge. Is that a right place to file such bug anyway?

Comment: @Vitas, Could you try this workaround, adding `pcie_aspm=off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. Source: http://pingtool.org/kernel-e1000e-eth0-error-reading-phy-register/